# Find especific directory and ignore other

Tags: linux, find

I need to find all the iplanets on one server and I was thinking to use this command:

```
find / type d -name https-* |  uniq
```

But at the same time I need to ignore some directories/file. I've been trying to use `!`, but it not always work. I have a command like this:

```
find / type d -name https-* ! -name https-admserv* ! -name conf_bk* ! -name alias* ! -name *db* ! -name ClassCache* |  uniq
```

I need to ignore all that. The directories `admserv`, `conf_bk`, `alias` and `tmp` and the files `*.db*`
Basically I need find this:

```
/opt/mw/iplanet/https-daniel.com
/opt/https-daniel1.com
/apps/https-daniel2.com
```

I only need to find the directory name. How can I ignore all the other stuff?

Comment: If you want to skip a whole directory, use `-prune`.

Comment: Also, you should put all the arguments with wildcards inside quotes, otherwise the wildcards will be expanded in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-prune` to keep from recursing into directories:

```
find / \( -type d \( -name 'https-admserv*' -o -name 'conf_bk*' -o -name 'alias*' -o -name 'tmp' \) -prune -o -type d -name 'https-*' -print
```

There's no need to ignore any files. You're only selecting `https-*` directories, so everything else is ignored.

And there's no need to pipe to `uniq`, since `find` never produces duplicates.